# JSON formatting Columns

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I'm attempting to output a MySQL table column into a JSON format.  After my query, in PHP I am doing this:

```
$json_data=array();
while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $json_data[] = array('name' => 'Model', 'data' => $m[1]);
}

print json_encode($json_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

`$m[1]` is simply a column in the table with numeric values.  My attempt yields a result like this:

```
[{"name":"Model","data":0},{"name":"Model","data":58},{"name":"Model","data":0},
{"name":"Model","data":0},{"name":"Model","data":84},{"name":"Model","data":15},
{"name":"Model","data":0},{"name":"Model","data":12},{"name":"Model","data":0},
{"name":"Model","data":102},{"name":"Model","data":0}]
```

However, I need the format to look like this (note that I don't want the surrounding `[` and `]` at the beginning/end as well):

```
{"name":"Model","data":[0, 58, 0, 0, 84, 15, 0, 12, 0, 102, 0]}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this

```
$json_data=array();
$json_data['name']='Model';
while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $json_data['data'][] = $m[1];
}

print json_encode($json_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
while ($m = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $json_data[] = $m[1];
}

print json_encode(['name'=>'Model', 'data'=>$json_data], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```